# Spring data native query filtering by List<String>

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-native-query

Given:
Interface projection model with

```
 String getType();
```

Postgres 13;
Hibernate+JPA+Spring data;
Query filter:

```
   " where ... "
 + " and (COALESCE(:types) is null or model.type in (:types)) "
```

Pageable method in repository contains param

```
 @Param("types") @Nullable List<String> types
```

generated SQL when null types is being passed:

```
and (COALESCE(?) is null or folderModel.contentType in (?))
```

error after it thrown:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
  Tips: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

There is no problem when I pass any nullable params in 'where' clause likewise when types isn't null and contains valid types. I tried to cast(model.type to varchar) with no any success. Any ideas?